# Multiple y axis sections in a multiplot

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-axes

I'v got a `multiplot  2,2` with `5 lines` in each plot, the lines range around the same values from `600-700` on the y value so they're overlapping.
I added `+60 +120 +180` and `+240` to the y values and it would do the trick but isn't there a way in gnuplot to add multiple sections on the `y` axes. So I'd plot the first line in the first section, second in the second and so on and each section ranges from `600-700`
one of the 4 plots in the multiplot looks like this:
[image]

My Code:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2 title "Spring Summer Fall Winter"
set title 'Spring'
plot 'Data1.csv' every ::614::637 using 2:3 w l title 'CI 0.2',\
"" every ::963::964 using 2:($3+20) w l title 'CI 0.4 [{/Symbol l}ave+20]',\
"" every ::1080::1084 using 2:($3+40) w l title 'CI 0.6 [{/Symbol l}ave+40]',
set title 'Sommer'
plot 'Data2.csv' every ::1074::1155 using 2:3 w l title 'CI 0.2',\
"" every ::2548::2618 using 2:($3+60) w l title 'CI 0.4 [{/Symbol l}ave+60]',\
"" every ::4017::4092 using 2:($3+120) w l title 'CI 0.6 [{/Symbol     l}ave+120]',\
"" every ::5580::5655 using 2:($3+180) w l title 'CI 0.8 [{/Symbol l}ave+180]',\
"" every ::7186::7280 using 2:($3+240) w l title 'CI 1.0 [{/Symbol l}ave+240]',
set title 'Fall'
plot 'Data3.csv' every ::43::43 using 2:3 w l title 'CI 0.2',\
"" every ::63::63 using 2:($3+20) w l title 'CI 0.4 [{/Symbol l}ave+20]',\
"" every ::87::87 using 2:($3+40) w l title 'CI 0.6 [{/Symbol l}ave+40]',\
"" every ::135::139 using 2:($3+60) w l title 'CI 0.8 [{/Symbol l}ave+60]',\
"" every ::311::362 using 2:($3+80) w l title 'CI 1.0 [{/Symbol l}ave+80]',
set title 'Winter' 
plot 'Data4.csv' using 2:3 every ::788::829 w l title 'CI 0.2',\
"" every ::1256::1268 using 2:($3+20) w l title 'CI 0.4 [{/Symbol l}ave+20]',\
"" every ::1512::1525 using 2:($3+40) w l title 'CI 0.6 [{/Symbol l}ave+40]',\
"" every ::1681::1686 using 2:($3+60) w l title 'CI 0.8 [{/Symbol l}ave+60]',
unset multiplot
unset output
```

So what I've already got is a Multiplot with one plot for each season:
In every Plot there are up to 5 lines showing some data. Most of the data on the y axes is in an area between 600 and 700 so in order to avoid overlapping lines which are hard to distinguish even with different colors I plotted the first line normally, and then all the other lines with some additional point (`+40` `+60`and so on) so that all the lines are not on the same spot in the plot but on top of each other, so you can compare tendencies and drifts.

What I want to know is if theres a way to simply cut the y axes into up to `5`areas each reaching from `600-700`so I can plot one line in the top area (`600-700`) the next one in the are below the one before and so on. So all lines are in the same value field  but on top of each other so you can distinguish between them easier but and don't have to mind the `+20`  or whatever value when looking ad the y axes, since each of those areas on the y axes could have tics and a grid.
Here's an image I made ...
[image]

Comment: From your question it is difficult to understand what you have and what you want to achieve instead. Maybe you can post some data (link to a file) and the code you have, so that we can take it from there?

Comment: I guess you will need a 2 x 10 multiplot for this. I'll try to find some time but this is rather involved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof of concept rather than a a complete solution but I think you can use this and start customizing from here:

```
set multiplot layout 6, 2

set format x ""      # no xtic labels
set ytics -4, 2, 4   # adequately spaced, non-overlapping ytic labels

set bmargin 0
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::0::4 w lp t "spring 1"
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::5::9 w lp t "summer 1"

set tmargin 0
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::10::14 w lp t "spring 2"
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::0::4 w lp t "summer 2"

set bmargin 1
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::15::19 w lp t "spring 3"
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::10::14 w lp t "summer 3"
set tmargin 1

set bmargin 0
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::0::4 w lp t "fall 1"
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::5::9 w lp t "winter 1"

set tmargin 0
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::10::14 w lp t "fall 2"
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::20::24 w lp t "winter 2"

set bmargin 1
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::5::9 w lp t "fall 3"
plot[][-5:5] "so.dat" every ::10::14 w lp t "winter 3"

unset multiplot
```

Resulting graph:

[image]

Data file `so.dat`:

```
1   -1.8351
2   0.6315
3   -1.3365
4   2.1251
5   -0.6708
6   -3.3965
7   -0.2298
8   0.4807
9   -2.4213
10  -0.5998
11  -1.0238
12  -0.2025
13  0.4362
14  -1.1263
15  3.3197
16  0.0337
17  -0.7374
18  1.1504
19  -0.1656
20  -0.4389
21  1.4645
22  1.6538
23  1.6362
24  -2.0363
25  -4.9741
```